# activate spring boot profile from maven profile

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-profiles

I want to separate my junit test and integration test separate. So I created a separate profile in pom.xml for the integration test as follows:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>integration-test</id>
    <properties>
        <test>IntegrationTestTrigger</test>
        <spring.profiles.active>integration-test</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
</profile>                                                                                  
<profiles>
```

The when I run the maven command `mvn test -Pintegration-test`, it is picking the test class as defined in the `<properties>` tag shown above as `IntegrationTestTrigger`. But it is not setting the `spring.profiles.active` property. So the test is starting with default profile. It is working fine with the maven command `mvn test -Dtest=IntegrationTestTrigger -Dspring.profiles.active=integration-test`

But as per my organisations jenkins setting, I need to run `mvn test -Pintegration-test` for the integration test, so I cannot add any extra environment variables to mvn command

Comment: The properties at the profile is meant for property substitution at the property file. Can you show the content of your properties file ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as @gtivari333 said, profile/properties section is only to be used for substitution in POM files (and other files processed by maven, if so desired).
To set JVM properties aka "system properties" in POM directly, for use during test execution, you need to set them using surefire plugin configuration like this:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <foo>bar</foo>
                            <spring.profiles.active>integration-test</spring.profiles.active>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties at the  is meant for property substitution at the .properties/.yml file inside resources folder.

Example:

application.yml:

```
spring:
   profiles:
       active: '@spring.profiles.active@'
```

pom.xml:

```
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

Here, the `@spring.profiles.active@` will be replaced with dev during compile(by maven-resources-plugin plugin). Spring Boot uses `@` as the resource delimiter at the spring-boot-starter-parent pom. You can change it to any character by changing the following property

```
//pom.xml
<project  .....>
  <properties>
    <resource.delimiter>@</resource.delimiter>
    ...
  </properties>
```

See https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/blob/master/pom.xml#L436 for an complete example

See also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven

Comment: There is no application.yml file used here. The profiles are activated through environment variable setting. When running maven command or running from eclipse I uses this command:
`mvn test -Dtest=IntegrationTestTrigger -Dspring.profiles.active=integration-test`

here the first variable which is `test` I was able to set through the properties as mentioned in my post. But the `spring.profiles.active` is not setting

Comment: "But as per my organisations jenkins setting, I need to run `mvn test -Pintegration-test` ".   `mvn test -Pintegration-test`  won't do anything to your spring app. Maven doesn't know how to talk to Spring. The way to interface between maven and spring is through the <properties> tag under <profile>, which would update the application.yml/.properties

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven this is already described in Spring Boot docs btw

Comment: I had seen this property expansion method in other stack overflow answer to similar question. But that is by the assumption that there is an application.yml/properties. But I dont keep such a file at present and that is not the first option I am preferring also. My observation is that I can run the following command:
`mvn test -Dtest=IntegrationTestTrigger -Dspring.profiles.active=integration-test`
Also the first property, which is `test` I am able to set through the profile as I mentioned in my post. Similarly I just want to set the second property also