# How to use profile variables to define final properties values?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

In Spring Boot, I know I can define profiles on `application.yml`. However, it's not clear to me how to achieve the same result as in this `pom.xml` snippet:

```
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <pucomex.config.redis.host>devhost</pucomex.config.redis.host>
            <pucomex.config.redis.port>5678</pucomex.config.redis.port>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>tst</id>
        <properties>
            <pucomex.config.redis.host>tsthost</pucomex.config.redis.host>
            <pucomex.config.redis.port>1234</pucomex.config.redis.port>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <!-- properties based on profile variables -->
                    <pucomex.config.redis.host>${pucomex.config.redis.host}</pucomex.config.redis.host>
                    <pucomex.config.redis.port>${pucomex.config.redis.port}</pucomex.config.redis.port>

                    <!-- global properties -->
                    <elastic.port>9200</elastic.port>
                    <elastic.rhlc.connect.timeout.ms>5000</elastic.rhlc.connect.timeout.ms>
                    <elastic.rhlc.socket.timeout.ms>60000</elastic.rhlc.socket.timeout.ms>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

In other words: I want to have some properties values varying according to each profile and then use them to define the value of another property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67118626/607637 does this help?

Comment: the idea is to map maven profile to spring boot at the application.yml|properties file to `spring.profiles.active`. That way when you compile your project with the profile (mvn compile -pProfile) ,  maven updates the properties file with the value. SPring Boot will then initialize correct application-PROFILE.yml file